# How to get an MS Access chart to stop duplicating in layout and print view?

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm trying to build charts into my report but the chart appears more than once when my report is in layout view or report view.

How can I get just one chart to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when the record source for the whole report (Report properties > Record Source) was removed, the chart stopped duplicating and now only appears once!